# Django html redirects but doesn't load page

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

I am creating a Django web application and have come across the following problem.

I have created a new html page called teamList.html, which when clicking a href hyperlink on the main page, should redirect to teamList page. The url in the browser, which starts as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/teamList`, but the page underneath doesn't change, but instead reloads the starting page.

The current application handles the login and main page in the html as such (default after login displays a graph):

```
#index.html
<body>
<img src="{% static "myApp/images/logo.gif" %}" alt="logo" />

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>currently logged in as: {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}
<p><a href="/logout">logout</a>
<p><a href="/teamList">Team List</a>

<div id="radarChart">    
{% block radarChartBlock %}{% endblock %}

</div>


{% else%}

<div id="login">
    {% block login %}{% endblock %}
</div>

{% endif %}

</body>
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
#http://localhost:8000/             
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^/teamList/$', views.renderTeamList, name='teamList')
)
```

EDIT: My views.py method for my teamList.html looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from myApp.models import FocusArea
from myApp.tables import TeamTable
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig

def renderTeamList(request):
table = TeamTable()
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request, 'teamList.html', {'table': table})
```

Comment: Where's your view? That's where you want to redirect.

Comment: is view return correctly .?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments there is a problem with your `urls.py`. Your regular expression for `teamList` url starts with `/` and therefore will not match `http://127.0.0.1:8000/teamList` as Django replaces a leading slash by default. From the docs:

> There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. For example, it’s ^articles, not ^/articles.

For more details see [Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example).